# 15 digit floating variable calculation in microcontroller

Tags: algorithm, arduino, numbers, calculator

I want to calculate an equation within a controller(Arduino)

> y = -0.0000000104529251928664x^3 + 0.0000928316793270531x^2 - 0.282333029643959x + 297.661280719026

Now the decimal values of the coefficients are important because "x" varies in thousands so cube term cannot be ignored. I have tried manipulating the equation in excel to reduce the coefficients but R^2 is lost in the process and I would like to avoid that.

[image]

Max variable size available in Arduino is 4byte. And on google search, I was not able to find an appropriate solution.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: floating point precision is probably not enough to do what you want.

Comment: What did you get manipulating the coefficients with Excel. It's not clear, can you post it ?

Comment: I mean when I reduce the no of digits then the whole curve just shifts from the data point that I am trying to fit to. (Its the best fit calibration curve equation that I have got from testing which i am trying to implement in Arduino)

Comment: With _x_ of 1000, these terms are comparable: why do you think that `float` isn't good enough?

Comment: I meant storing the coefficient values, float is not large enough to hold that.

Comment: Try fitting the curve in different segments - so for different ranges have different equations.

Comment: I didn't think of that. That's a great idea actually. But that would call for rechecking and verification if it's working as expected and I am short of time as well. So if i can get some solution with the same equation then it would be great.

Comment: Are you sure that the loss of precision using float is so important? See https://ideone.com/5XpEvk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since

```
-0.0000000104529251928664 ^ (1/3) = - 0.0021864822
0.0000928316793270531 ^ (1/2) = 0.00963491978
```

The formula

```
y = -0.0000000104529251928664x^3 + 0.0000928316793270531x^2 - 0.282333029643959x + 297.661280719026
```

Can be rewritten:

```
y = -(0.0021864822 * x)^3 + (0.00963491978 * x)^2 - 0.282333029643959 * x + 297.661280719026
```

---

Rounding all coefficients to 10 decimal places, we get:

```
y = -(0.0021864822 * x)^3 + (0.00963491978 * x)^2 - 0.2823330296 * x + 297.6612807
```

But I don't know Arduino, I'm not sure what the correct number of decimal places is, nor do I know what the compiler will accept or refuse.

Comment: That was really smart approach. thanks. It did help. Let me give that a try and i will get back with results. Thank you once again.

Comment: Though i am still wondering about the last coefficient. But i appreciate the effort.

Comment: I made a mistake I changed a (-) into a (+) for the 0.28...*x coefficient. This has been corrected now.

Comment: For the last coefficients, truncation won't be a big problem, especially 297, if x is in thousands.

Comment: Hey, I checked the equation in Arduino as well and it works perfectly. thank you again for help.